# Discord.js - Get a user by ID or mention

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
if (!message.mentions.members.first() && !(args[0])) return message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}>: ${insultList[Math.floor(Math.random() * insultList.length)]}`);

const user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

if (!user) return message.inlineReply(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor("D9B3FF").setTitle("Error").setDescription("User not found."));

message.channel.send(`${user}: ${insultList[Math.floor(Math.random() * insultList.length)]}`);
```

An !insult command; `insultList` being an array of strings. However, calling the command with user IDs (of guild members) only occasionally works; it usually returns `User not found`. Everything else works as intended.

Comment: Are you trying to use this command on few people in the same time or only 1?

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft one at a time; a mention or valid user ID should ping the user with an insult, an invalid args should send the error message, and calling the command without input should ping the message author with an insult

Comment: Can you also add error message you get to your question please?

Comment: adding a try...catch on getting the user from the ID doesn't output any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` will return `false` if the id of `args[0]` corresponds to an uncached member.

1. Use [GuildMemberManager#fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) to fetch the member if they were not mentioned
2. Use [(GuildMember|User)#toString()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=toString) to parse member objects into mentions, no need to build them from scratch (`<@id>`)

```js
const insult = insultList[Math.floor(Math.random() * insultList.length)];

if (!message.mentions.members.first() && !(args[0])) return message.channel.send(`${message.author.toString()}: ${insult}`);

try {
   const user = message.mentions.members.first() || (await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]));
   if (!user) return message.inlineReply(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor("D9B3FF").setTitle("Error").setDescription("User not found."));

   message.channel.send(`${user.toString()}: ${insult}`);
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
}
```

Ensure you have the Guild Member's Intent enabled and you make your parent function is asynchronous for this example. Otherwise resolve the promise of `.fetch()` with callbacks.

Comment: I think you mean `!user` will return `true`